# Why are canactivate, candeactivate sort of imports are shown as deprecated?

Tags: angular

Almost all the import statements containing CanActivate, CanDeactivate sort of route guards are shown as deprecated. Will it show implications like failing the authentication/authorization features of the application.

Am I thinking too much, or my assumption is right? Should I fix these deprecations?

Comment: Using a "deprecated" method does not (yet) lead to errors. (therefore deprecations are only reported as warnings but not as errors). "deprecated" only means, that this method will/may be removed in a future release. So yeah, you should fix them, because when you upgrade to the next version, those methods may not be contained anymore and then indeed lead to errors.

Comment: For the "why": Because the developers decided to refactor the API and want to remove them in a future release, and thus marked them as deprecated ...

Answer (score 1):

Are they deprecated?  Yes.

Is there anything to worry about? No.

Defiantly they were a go to feature for quite some time and with the latest versions of Angular they experience the deprecation in favor of `functional guards`.

Its nothing that should be done on spot, but if an bigger app is in question that's something that should be looked into thought this year, since Angular is evolving rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

`canActivate` classes are deprecated. you should now use functional guards instead https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#preventing-unauthorized-access

example:

```
export function userHasPermission(permission: string): CanActivateFn {
  return (snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
    const user = inject(UserService).getUser();
    return user.permissions.include(permission);
  }
}
```

usage:

```
canActivate: [userHasPermission('modify-items')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular team has deprecated the class-based route guards.

> **Deprecated:** Class-based `Route` guards are deprecated in favor of functional guards. An injectable class can be used as a functional
> guard using the `inject` function: `canActivate: [() => inject(myGuard).canActivate()].`

It means we no longer need to import the `canActivate` from a class and implement it in our guard. Instead, we can directly use the `canActivate` method with our logic.

`src/app/auth/auth.guard.ts`

```js
export const authGuard = () => {
  console.log('authGuard#canActivate called');
  return true;
};
```

`src/app/admin/admin-routing.module.ts`

```js
import {authGuard} from '../auth/auth.guard';

import {AdminDashboardComponent} from './admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import {AdminComponent} from './admin/admin.component';
import {ManageCrisesComponent} from './manage-crises/manage-crises.component';
import {ManageHeroesComponent} from './manage-heroes/manage-heroes.component';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminComponent,
  canActivate: [authGuard],

  children: [{
    path: '',
    children: [
      {path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent},
      {path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent},
      {path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent}
    ],
  }]
}];

@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)], exports: [RouterModule]})
export class AdminRoutingModule {
}
```

For further info: [Angular Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#guard-the-admin-feature)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question explicitly... Because Angular is running out of features to add and need to make changes for the sake of making changes. Read the discussions on github for the deprecation commit and you can see that they cannot provide a valid reason themselves.

The real nightmare of this is that you could previously search for all your guard classes by looking at anything that referenced/implemented CanActivate

Now you're stuck looking for random unattached functions that could be anywhere in a codebase depending on who worked on it prior and their preferences for placing functionality.

Disappointingly this was a very regressive act on the part of the Angular team. :(

Comment: link please for the referenced commit discussion